# Where can I find free minitype icons that can be used as buttons?

Tags: icons

Where can I find free minitype icons that can be used as buttons?
Which good websites can be available?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about icon collections

Answer (score 0):

I often use these websites:

[http://365psd.com/](http://ddfeccaf.tinylinks.co)

ui-cloud.com/free-ui-elements/

357fc735.goneviral.com

www.deviantart.com

......

You can try!

Comment: The question is off topic to the site. which makes the answer to.